# Using a variable to read from json?

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get my Python bot to use a variable I already defined (random), to read a JSON file and send me the URL that corresponds to the variable it was given.

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

max = data["max"]["max"]
random = random.randint(1, max)
url = data[random]["url"]
```

But when I run the bot it goes all "KeyError", and after checking by replacing `url[random]["url"]` by `url["5"]["url"]` it correctly sent me the url that corresponds to 5
I'm not sure if it's impossible to do what I'm trying to do this way, or if there's some kind of special format I have to use:

here's my question, and I really don't know how to phrase it properly since I don't know the terminology so:

Is there a simple way to use this "random" variable when asking my bot to read from a json ?

I'd rather use this kind of formating since it's something I understand and am used to but if it's not possible I don't mind trying something else

If you're wondering how the json looks like it goes a bit like :

```
{
"max": {"max":139},
"1": {stuff here},
"2": {stuff here},
"3": {stuff here},
"4": {stuff here},
"etc"...
}
```

Comment: `random.randint` returns an integer (as the name implies). You need to convert it to a string. Also don't call it `random`, it will stomp on the name of the module. `rdm = str(random.randint(1, max))`. **Edit**: Don't use `max` as a variable name either- it will overwrite `__builtin__.max`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `random.randint` returns an integer number, while the dictionary you are accessing has string keys.  You can solve this by wrapping `str` around the random variable when accessing the dictionary:

```
url = data[str(random)]["url"]
```

Comment: Also as @pault mentioned in his comment, don't name your variable the same as a module to prevent future code from failing.

Comment: It's worth noting that JSON will not accept ints as keys. They automatically get converted to strings. Bitten by that before :)

Answer (score 1):

You json file has strings as keys. Try:

```
url = data[str(random)]["url"]
```